# A stub framework for a big form?

Tags: stub, stubby4j

We are having a huge page having lot of line items ,each Line item has 40+ fields . There is no submit button ,a change in every field triggers a submit to server . We are currently using [stubby4J](https://stubby4j.com) , we end up mocking every combination of request and which  is huge as a file and also the count of files is also huge . The difference between two stub request files are just two parameters , but still we have 40+ parameters in stub request file. We are currently using  stubby4J ,is there a better alternative for our case or even a configuration in stubby4j taht help us ease our pain ?

Answer (score 1):

It is a very late reply, but I thought to add my 2 cents anyway:

[stubby4j](https://stubby4j.com) will ignore matching parameters that were not stubbed. Instead of stubbing all 40+ params, maybe consider stubbing the minimal number params required for matching? Also, stubby4j support regex, have you tried that?

Please have a look at stubby4j docs:

1. [Regex stubbing for dynamic matching](https://stubby4j.com/docs/http_endpoint_configuration_howto.html#regex-stubbing-for-dynamic-matching)
2. [Regex stubbing for XML content](https://stubby4j.com/docs/http_endpoint_configuration_howto.html#regex-stubbing-for-xml-content)